# Display sum function value for only one category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data = {'Person': ['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','b','c'],
        'months':['Jan','Jan','Jan','Jan','Feb','Feb','Feb','Feb','March','March'],
        'income':[100,75,80,56,48,56,37,48,95,65]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.groupby(['Person'])['income'].sum()
```

Output:

```
Person  
a    148  
b    226  
c    182  
d    104  
Name: income, dtype: int64
```

But I want to display data for only `a`. How can I do that?

Comment: can you show an example of your expected output? does df.head(1) not work?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Person'])['income'].sum().loc['a']` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use `groupby` if you only need `a`?

```
df.loc[df["Person"].eq("a"),"income"].sum()

#148
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df[df['Person'] == 'a'].groupby(['Person'])['income'].sum()
```

**Output**

```
Person
a    148
Name: income, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `groupby`, just use `eq` and `sum`:

```
print(df.loc[df['Person'].eq('a'), 'income'].sum())
```

Output:

```
148
```